# How do I end a program, and stop the user from being prompted?

Tags: java, netbeans

When the user enters a width that is less than or equal to 0, the program should end, and not prompt the user for a length, or output an area or perimeter. How do I do this WITHOUT using System.exit(0)?!?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter a Width: ");
    double width = k.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please Enter a Length: ");
    double length = k.nextDouble();
    double area = width * length; 
    System.out.println("The Area is: " + area);
    double perimeter = 2 * (width + length);
    System.out.println("The Perimeter is: " + perimeter);

    if (width <=0)
        System.out.println("The Width Must Be Greater Than 0");

    else if (length <=0)
        System.out.println("The Length Must Be Greater Than 0");

    if (width == length)
    System.out.println("The Shape is a Square"); 

    else if (width != length)
    System.out.println("The Shape is a Rectangle");
```

Comment: The code you posted indicates you know how to use `if` statements.  Try putting your prompts inside some.

Answer (score 1):

You can always jump out of a method with `return`

In your case:

```
...
System.out.print("Please Enter a Width: ");
double width = k.nextDouble();
if (width <= 0)
    return;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your conditional statements so the rest of the code is executed only if the width is greater than 0:

```
Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Please Enter a Width: ");
double width = k.nextDouble();
if (width <=0)
{
    System.out.println("The Width Must Be Greater Than 0");
}
else 
{
    System.out.print("Please Enter a Length: ");
    double length = k.nextDouble();
    double area = width * length; 
    System.out.println("The Area is: " + area);
    double perimeter = 2 * (width + length);
    System.out.println("The Perimeter is: " + perimeter);
    if (length <=0)
        System.out.println("The Length Must Be Greater Than 0");
    if (width == length)
        System.out.println("The Shape is a Square"); 
    else if (width != length)
        System.out.println("The Shape is a Rectangle");
}
```

Comment: This is probably a bit 'cleaner' than my answer ;) +1

Comment: This code is incorrect -- the logic must be within the lines which prompt the user for input, not after.

Comment: @Trobbins your correct I didn't look at the code close enough...Hopefully that is enough for the user to go on though it is a pretty simple change to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If the `width` is less than zero, the program will exit and not prompt the user for the `length`. I've expanded that logic into the `length` prompt, such that if the `length` is less than 0, the program stops as well.

Working off of [brso05'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32951445/4771017)s logic, I've come up with the below suggestion:

```
Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Please Enter a Width: ");
double width = k.nextDouble();

if (width <=0){
    System.out.println("The Width Must Be Greater Than 0");
}
else{
    System.out.print("Please Enter a Length: ");
    double length = k.nextDouble();

    if (length <=0){
        System.out.println("The Length Must Be Greater Than 0");
    }
    else{
         double area = width * length; 
         System.out.println("The Area is: " + area);
         ...
    }
}
```